# istioctl manifest apply with custom parameters

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I want to apply the default manifest with some custom parameters such as namespace and tolerations but I have no idea how to pass tolerations parameters into the manifest.

and I used the command and custom parameters to apply the below

```
istioctl manifest --kubeconfig /home/admin_config apply -f value.yaml --set xxxxx=aaaa
```

and the toleration parameters should follow the below

```
tolerations:
- key: usage
  effect: NoSchedule 
  operator: Equal
  value: system
```

I'm new in the istio and hard to understand how to pass the tolerations as parameter syntax such as `--set xxxxx=aaaa`

Has anyone experienced that before?